# Victory chart y axis value cropped

Tags: javascript, css, victory-charts

I have 7 digits values and my VictoryChart component just showed 5 digits how to extend the width of the y-axis to show whole digits?[image]

```
  <div>
        <h2 style={{backgroundColor:"purple",color:"white",height:"2vw"}}>PeerConnectionsRTCInboundRTPAudioStream_BytesReceived</h2>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', textAlign: 'center', marginBottom:"3vw"}}>
        <div style={{"height" : "15vw", "width" : "15vw",marginLeft:"3vw"}}>
        <VictoryChart
          theme={VictoryTheme.material}
 
        >
          <VictoryLine
            style={{
              data: { stroke: "red" },
              parent: { border: "1px solid #ccc"},
              
        
            }}
            
            data={MinArr}
          />
          
        </VictoryChart>

        </div>
        
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding left padding should give enough room to the numbers

<VictoryChart padding: { top: 20, bottom: 50, left: 60, right: 60 } />

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).